# getting background to randomize on load?

Tags: javascript, html

So yeah I'm not very good at getting this page to do this. I had the goal to make a background apply a random color. So I put some colors into an array and decided to select a random one from it. This was my attempt, but it didn't tahe affect.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>   
<body>   
<script>    
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink"];
bodyObject.bgColor=colors[r].toString(); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this code as it's most resilient to alteration;

```
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink"];
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*colors.length-1)+1);
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].bgColor=colors[r];
```

Note that I originally suggested that you give your body tag an id "bodyObject", which is in fact the easiest way to fix the code as you'd written it, and was the cause of your bug, but that suggestion was poorly received.

Note here however, that I've also re-ordered a couple of lines allowing you to use the length property which is more robust to the numbers of items in your array.

You could also generate colours from scales of RGBs, but I'm not sure what effect you're going for.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
<script>    
window.onload = function(){
var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink"];
document.body.style.backgroundColor =colors[r]; 
}
</script>
```

Comment: the toString method is redundant. The colors are already strings

Answer (score 0):

If you are to use bodyObject as a variable you need to define it first in your code:

```
var r          = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1),
    colors     = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "pink"],
    bodyObject = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

bodyObject.bgColor=colors[r]; // @Matanya to string not required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422215/getting-background-to-randomize-on-load#comment25303047_17422278
```